# Two errors while trying to capture .getMouse in zelles graphics

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

```
#Nicolas Conde COMP 151-005 10-3-17

from graphics import *

def main():

    #DataStorage
    NumberOfShapes = 0.0
    ShapeType = 0.0
    ShapeSpecs = 0.0
    p1 = 0.0
    p2 = 0.0

    #GraphicsWindow
    win = GraphWin("Drawing Shapes", 500, 500)

    #Input
    print("*** Drawing Shapes ***")
    NumberOfShapes = int(input("Select the number of shapes: "))

    #For loops begin here, each shape has their own for loop. Anything that is a commment within the for loop is from checkpoint 1 of the project.
    for i in range (NumberOfShapes):
        ShapeType = input("Select the shape type: ")

        #Rectangle
        if ShapeType == "R":
            ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the upper left and lower right points of the rectangle): ")
            p1 = win.getMouse()
            p2 = win.getMouse()
            #ShapeSpecs = ShapeSpecs.split(',')
            Rect = Rectangle(p1,p2) #(Point(int(ShapeSpecs[0]),int(ShapeSpecs[1])), Point(int(ShapeSpecs[2]),int(ShapeSpecs[3])))
            Rect.draw(win)

        #Oval
        if ShapeType == "O":
            ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the upper left and lower right points of the oval): ")
            p1 = win.getMouse()
            p2 = win.getMouse()
            #ShapeSpecs = ShapeSpecs.split(',')
            Ovl = Oval(p1,p2) #(Point(int(ShapeSpecs[0]),int(ShapeSpecs[1])), Point(int(ShapeSpecs[2]),int(ShapeSpecs[3])))
            Ovl.draw(win)


        #Circle
        if ShapeType == "C":
            ShapeSpecs = int("Enter the radius: ")
            ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the center of the circle: ")
            p1 = win.getMouse()
            #ShapeSpecs = ShapeSpecs.split(',')
            Circ = Circle #(Point(int(ShapeSpecs[0]), int(ShapeSpecs[1])), float(ShapeSpecs[2]))
            Circ.draw(win)
```

Here is where the first issue is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/nicol/OneDrive - Bridgewater State University/Freshman Year 2017/Semester 1/Computer Science I - COMP 151 - 005 Haleh Khojasteh/Project-2-Drawing Shapes/NicolasCondeProject2.py", line 91, in <module>
        main()
File "C:/Users/nicol/OneDrive - Bridgewater State University/Freshman Year 2017/Semester 1/Computer Science I - COMP 151 - 005 Haleh Khojasteh/Project-2-Drawing Shapes/NicolasCondeProject2.py", line 46, in main
        ShapeSpecs = int("Enter the radius: ")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Enter the radius: '
```

Continuing with the code:

```
        #Line
        if ShapeType == "L":
            ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on two points of the line): ")
            p1 = win.getMouse()
            p2 = win.getMouse()
            #ShapeSpecs = ShapeSpecs.split(',')
            Lin = Line(p1,p2) #(Point(int(ShapeSpecs[0]), int(ShapeSpecs[1])), Point(int(ShapeSpecs[2]), int(ShapeSpecs[3])))
            Lin.draw(win)

        #Text
        if ShapeType == "T":
            ShapeSpecs = input("Enter the text: ")
            ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the center of the text: ")
            p1 = win.getMouse()
            #ShapeSpecs = ShapeSpecs.split(',')
            Txt = Text(p1) #(Point(int(ShapeSpecs[0]), int(ShapeSpecs[1])), (ShapeSpecs[2]))
            Txt.draw(win)
```

Here's where the second issue is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/nicol/OneDrive - Bridgewater State University/Freshman Year 2017/Semester 1/Computer Science I - COMP 151 - 005 Haleh Khojasteh/Project-2-Drawing Shapes/NicolasCondeProject2.py", line 77, in <module>
        main()
File "C:/Users/nicol/OneDrive - Bridgewater State University/Freshman Year 2017/Semester 1/Computer Science I - COMP 151 - 005 Haleh Khojasteh/Project-2-Drawing Shapes/NicolasCondeProject2.py", line 63, in main
        Txt = Text(p1) #(Point(int(ShapeSpecs[0]), int(ShapeSpecs[1])), (ShapeSpecs[2]))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

Continuing with the code:

```
        #Point
        if ShapeType == "P":
            ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the point location: ")
            p1 = win.getMouse()
            #ShapeSpecs = ShapeSpecs.split(',')
            Pnt = Point(p1) #(int(ShapeSpecs[0]), int(ShapeSpecs[1]))
            Pnt.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `int` as if it's the same as `input`

```
ShapeSpecs = int("Enter the radius: ")
```

It should be two nested calls:

```
ShapeSpecs = int(input("Enter the radius: "))
```

This logic overwrites the user input and fails to pass text to `Text()`:

```
ShapeSpecs = input("Enter the text: ")
ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the center of the text: ")
p1 = win.getMouse()
Txt = Text(p1)
```

Instead try:

```
ShapeText = input("Enter the text: ")
ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the center of the text: ")
p1 = win.getMouse()
Txt = Text(p1, ShapeText)
```

You make a similar error in the circle logic:

```
ShapeSpecs = int("Enter the radius: ")
ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the center of the circle: ")
p1 = win.getMouse()
Circ = Circle
Circ.draw(win)
```

overwriting the radius before you can make use of it:

```
ShapeRadius = int("Enter the radius: ")
ShapeSpecs = print("Click your mouse on the center of the circle: ")
p1 = win.getMouse()
Circ = Circle(p1, ShapeRadius)
Circ.draw(win)
```